# CSS Animation to slide left

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to do a CSS Animation where the block moves completely to the left but it doesn't seem to work:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}

.c1{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slideout;
}

@keyframes slideout {
    from {
        margin-right: 50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 100%;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="c1">
```

I tried using id instead of class but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
I took a look at this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

And turns out I needed to use the width property!

```
@keyframes slideout {
    from {
        margin-right: 50%;
        width: 50%;
    }

    to {
        margin-right: 100%;
        width: 0%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  }

.c1{
  width              : 50vw;
  height             : 100vh;
  animation-duration : 3s;
  animation-name     : slideout;
  background-color   : aqua;
  }
@keyframes slideout {
  from { margin-left : 0;     }
  to   { margin-left : -50vw; }
  }
```

```html
<div class="c1">
```